# replacing *args in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, replace, args

The goal is to replace all characters within a string using a for loop and `replace`. 
My code looks like this:

```
strand_1 = input("type DNA sequence here: ")
for i in ("a", "t"),("t", "a"),("g", "c"),("c", "g"):
    comp_strand = strand_1.replace(*i)

print(f' the complementary strand is: {comp_strand.upper()}')
```

The output for using 'agtcagtcagtc' looks like this:

```
type DNA sequence here: agtcagtcagtc
 the complementary strand is: AGTGAGTGAGTG
```

For some reason i don't understand, only the last pair ("c", "g") actually gets replaced while the others won't.

What might be the cause for this to happen, and how can i make this work?

Comment: Think about the logic here.  Every iteration you take the *original* input, replace characters, and then assign it to `comp_strand`.  Every iteration you throw out the changes from the previous iteration.

Comment: Try stepping through your code with a debugger to see what's happening, like [Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/). Hint: look at how `comp_strand` changes. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: Note that if you "fix" this to operate on the same string every time, it still won't do what you want, because you do the swaps one character at a time.  For example, `'atta'` would become `'tttt'` after the first iteration, and then `'aaaa'` after the second.  You can use [`maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to work around this.

Comment: Got it. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you're overwriting `comp_strand` each loop, and not saving the result. However even if you fix that, it still won't work, as [0x5453](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3282436/0x5453) explained in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61579982/replacing-args-in-a-for-loop/61580201#comment108928460_61579982):

> it still won't do what you want, because you do the swaps one character at a time. For example, `'atta'` would become `'tttt'` after the first iteration, and then `'aaaa'` after the second.

The better solution for multiple replacements is [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) with [`str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans). For example:

```
table = str.maketrans('atgc', 'tacg')
strand = 'agtcagtcagtc'
complementary = strand.translate(table)
print(complementary)  # -> tcagtcagtcag
```

Answer (score 0):

@0x5453 explained why the code is broken, I suggest how to fix it:

```
strand_1 = input("type DNA sequence here: ")
comp_strand = strand1.translate(str.maketrans('atcg', 'tagc'))
print(f' the complementary strand is: {comp_strand.upper()}')
```